# Specs2 - close JDBC connection after each test case

Tags: scala, specs2

I implemented specs2 specification that looks something like this:

```
class MySpec extends Specification {

  "My database query" should {

    "return some results " in {
      val conn = createJdbcConn()

      try {
        // matcher here...
      } finally {
        conn.close()
      }
    }
}
```

This ugly boilerplate is repeated in all my test cases. I have to open (and then close) a new connection for each `in`.

What is the idiomatic way in Specs2 close resources such as in this case - perhaps using the `After` (or `BeforeAfter`) trait to properly close the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the `FixtureExample` trait introduced in 2.0, to avoid using a variable:

```
import org.specs2._
import specification._
import execute._

trait DbFixture extends FixtureExample[JdbcConnection] {
  // type alias for more concise code
  type DBC = JdbcConnection

  /**
   * open the connection, call the code, close the connection
   */
  def fixture[R : AsResult](f: JdbcConnection => R): Result = {
    val connection = createJdbcConnection

    try     AsResult(f(connection))
    finally connection.close
  }
}

class MySpec extends Specification with DbFixture {
  "My database query" should {
    "return some results" in { connection: DBC =>
       // do something with the connection
       success
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to use a trait, and then your tests that need a db connection can just extend the trait (I'm not thrilled about the `var`, but it's the easiest way to do this):

```
  trait DbTestLifeCycle extends BeforeAfterExample {

    var dbConn:Option[YourDbConnection] = None

    protected def before: Any = {
      dbConn = Option(createJdbcConn())
    }

    protected def after: Any = {
      dbConn.map(_.close())
    }
  }
```

So your test would look like this:

```
  class MySpec extends Specification with DbTestLifeCycle {

    "My database query" should {

      "return some results " in {
        dbConn.map(conn => //do something in the db)
        // matcher here...
      }
    }
  }
```